# How to find path_similarity for lemmas in spanish?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, wordnet, difflib, open-multilingual-wordnet

When I try to find path_similarity or whether two English words are synonyms, I am able to execute for English, but when I try the same for Spanish, it shows an error.

Please find the attached the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: WordNet is a lexical database for the English language which groups **English** words into sets of synonyms called `synsets`. So, when you use `synsets`, the word MUST be English.

Comment: For future questions, it is better if you copy and paste the *text* into your question (wrapped in triple backticks), rather than a screenshot. That way people can copy your code into their editor and see if they can reproduce the problem. The easier you make it for people to play with your code, the more likely you are to get a useful answer.  (Also try to make it self-contained, so include at the top the `import` lines: that way people can see if you are missing, e.g. the Spanish data.)